# How to call Excel formula using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, automation

I am using below mentioned formula to filter out the unwanted text from a Cell. I would like to use this formula via VBA, i have tried some method that includes Sub Formula_Property and Recording Macro but not successful.

The formula is mentioned below:

```
=LEFT(A3,MIN(FIND({1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0},A3 & "1234567890"))-1)
```

The Main data is available in Sheet1 ColumnA2:A5000 and I would like the filtered text (Result) in Sheet3 column B2:B5000.

Is there anyway i can automate this using VBA, that would be helpful for me much.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Parse Left of First Digit

```vb
Sub ParseLeftOfDigit()
    
    Dim Data(): Data = Sheet1.Range("A2:A5000").Value
    
    Dim r As Long, n As Long, rStr As String
    
    For r = 1 To UBound(Data, 1)
        rStr = CStr(Data(r, 1))
        For n = 1 To Len(rStr)
            If Mid(rStr, n, 1) Like "#" Then
                Data(r, 1) = Mid(rStr, 1, n - 1)
                Exit For
            End If
        Next n
    Next r
    
    Sheet3.Range("B2:B5000").Value = Data

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

This macro will apply that formula to the range you wish.

```
Sub Filter_Text_Formula()
Sheets("Sheet3").Range("B2:B5000").FormulaR1C1 = "=LEFT(Sheet1!RC[-1],MIN(FIND({1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0},Sheet1!RC[-1] & ""1234567890""))-1)"
End Sub
```

Comment: Dear @Spencer Barnes It is giving error "Compile Error" Expected End of Statement and this highlights these numbers in formula 1234567890

Comment: You probably need to escape those quotes.

Comment: Yes, the ending should read `& ""1234567890""))-1)"`

Comment: Thanks @CLR and @ Gravitate, you're both right - editing my answer now to suit.

Comment: You put `& ""1234567890"))-1)""`, instead of `& ""1234567890""))-1)"`... I have now corrected it for you.

Comment: However @VBasic2008 code has one more option included which is that it automatically stops the code at the last cell and do not proceed after it. But thank you everyone so much